# How would I add sliders to increase the sides of my Polygons, and draw more of them without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

Currently I'm drawing vertices to create polygons, I would like to add sliders to allow a user to increase or decrease the amount of sides the polygons have and the amount drawn. Also having the canvas update with refreshing.
I've tried adding a slider to control the noOfSides but I've had no luck.
Thanks for your time and help.

```js
let noOfShapes = 3;
let noOfSides;
let rx, ry, drx, dry, rd1, rd2, drd1, drd2;
let threshold = 1000;
let fillColour;
let strokeThick;
let sidesSlider;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1240, 1754);
    noLoop();
    //  background(0, 230)
    colorMode(RGB)
    rectMode(CENTER);
    strokeWeight(3);
    //noOfSides = 3;
    fillColour = random(0, 255);
    sidesSlider = createSlider(4, 12, 3);
    sidesSlider.position(width + 20, 0);
    sidesSlider.style('width', '150px');
}

function draw() {
    background(0, 230)
    noOfSides = sidesSlider.value();

    for (let x = 0; x < noOfShapes; x++) {

        do {
            rx = [];
            ry = [];
            rd1 = [];
            rd2 = [];

            for (let y = 0; y < noOfSides; y++) {
                rx.push(random(10, width - 20));
                ry.push(random(10, height - 20));
                rd1.push(rx[y] * 1 + ry[y] * 1);
                rd2.push(rx[y] * 1 - ry[y] * 1);
            }

            drx = max(rx) - min(rx);
            dry = max(ry) - min(ry);
            drd1 = max(rd1) - min(rd1);
            drd2 = max(rd2) - min(rd2);
        }
        while (drx < threshold || dry < threshold || drd1 < threshold || drd2 < threshold)

        beginShape();
        stroke(255);
        fill(random(1, 255), random(1, 255), random(1, 255), 150);
        for (let y = 0; y < rx.length; y++) {
            vertex(rx[y], ry[y]);
        }
        endShape(CLOSE);
    }

    for (let x = 20; x <= width; x = x + 20) {
        blendMode(DODGE);
        stroke(255);
        beginShape();
        vertex(x, 0)
        vertex(x, height + 20)
        endShape();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, you need to re-draw your shapes whenever slider changes since you are using `noLoop()`.
To do that you can easily define an on change event like this:

```js
sidesSlider.input(sliderChange);
```

And i suggest you to assign `noOfSides` variable's value in that function. After that call the `draw` funtion again.

```js
function sliderChange() {
  noOfSides = sidesSlider.value();
  draw();
}
```

Since you would remove assigning the value to `noOfSides` in `draw` function you need to set a default value to that variable either on initialization or in `setup function.

```
...
noOfSides = 3;
...
```

Then you are almost good to go, only thing that i don't quite understand was you last part of the code. I removed that part and it works as expected at the moment. 
Please be aware that you are setting background color with `alpha` value. That leads: on each rendering of shapes, latest shapes silhouette are still barely visible.

Here is the latest version of your code:
https://editor.p5js.org/darcane/sketches/5wpp6UgXI